# is there anyway to delete unused docker images from the AzureDevops Build server in automated way?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We have multiple AzureDevops Buildagents, whicha re using for docker image build and push to acr as aprt of build pipelines. In release stage , these built images are directly pulled from the ACR and deployed to AKS. But not sure why the devops build agents are still having these images in its cache directory, which is causing low disk issue frequently. So looking for an automated way where the old images should be cleaned  automatically regularly, say for images older than 50 days, these should be automatically deleted from the build agents. We have Azuredevops pools maintenance jobs to cleanup the stale foldrs in the working directory, sameway do we have an outof box or automated way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should opt-in for 2 different strategies:

1. Delete the locally built images just after pushing them to your remote registry
2. Schedule (weekly or monthly depending on how fast you're running low on space) a `docker image prune` operation (you can also filter it https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images) and also a `docker system prune` operation (https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything)

NB: Prune operations will lead your first subsequent build operation to be slower (no more cache, no more reusable layers...)

Comment: Thanks.. I decided to use this command to cleanup the images for last 3 months. "docker image prune --all --filter "until=720h".   I created a release pipelie with bash command task in it to pass the above command. But i am not sure , How i can ensure to run this command in AZuredevops pipeline to all the agents in the agentpool.